# Is Spotify an acceptable way to host audio sample?

Tags: discussion

I am preparing a question which might include an audio sample. It seems the only host I could find is Spotify.

Can I ask a question that includes a link to Spotify?

Comment: First, is your question on topic? https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14917/191178

Comment: A bit curious how hosting on Spotify is easier than, say, SoundCloud...

Comment: I bet spotify would take this content down if you uploaded it there. They're in the business of hosting music and podcasts, and it sounds like your content is neither of those. Try soundcloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotify is not on the banned list; you can link there if relevant to your question as much as any other site.

That said, please note that transcription requests, accent or pronunciation reviews, and similar requests that require playing a video or audio clip are not accepted, as they are unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.