# How can I upload a short audio clip of English so that I can ask for help with its transcription

Tags: discussion, pronunciation

Can I upload here a audio clip of English,like .mp3 or .wma
so that some native speakers may help me with its transcription

Comment: You should take the [tour]. This site is not a free transcription service.

Comment: In short, you cannot. The site aims to service questions which have broad utility or interest; like a library, we want our collection to offer the most help to the largest amount of people possible. Your clip will only ever be of interest to you, and not help anyone else in the future.

Comment: For non-native English speakers, often is not the grammar,the phrases or any kind of literal usages that confuse them, but is the sound of native speakers that frustrates them. so it's ok this site has its own service type,but I beg to differ that my clip will only benefit myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are audio- and video-only questions on-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/are-audio-and-video-only-questions-on-topic)